# transfering the linux to window Error in jni

Tags: c++, linux, java-native-interface

while transfering the whole project from linux to window it will show the below error i have set the path change the linuxgcc to mingw gcc 
please help me out

```
 Info: Internal Builder is used for build
    g++ -L/home/synan_usb/synan_FPR/syntec_lib -L/home/synan_usb/lib -L/home/synan_usb/synan_FPR/synan_src -shared -o libsynanJNI.dll "src\\synanJNI.o" -lsynan -lcyusb 
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsyntec
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcyusb
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Verify your library path on your windows machine.  Do you have a C:\home\synan_usb\synan_FPR\syntec_lib and C:\home\synan_usb\lib directories?